# iOS : How to override the button action of UIWebView and call our own Objective C method

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am loading a url in UIWebView in iOS. the url contains a button. I want to call a objective C method, when i click on this button. Please help.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: The button belongs to the web page. You cannot override it, because there is nothing on iOS side to be overridden. The best you could do is to detect a click.

Comment: You could use a bridge for sending messages between UIWebView and JavaScript

Comment: How can detect the click? Can you please the source code.

Comment: Basically I am loading a url in uiwebview and there is a Submit button, on the click of this button, I need to open my own viewcontroller.

Answer (score 4):

This is source code

```
NSString *strUrl = @"<html><body><button type=\"button\" id=\"success_id\" style=\"width:200px;margin:0px auto;text-align:center; background:#1B2F77;color:#fff;padding:10px;font-size:10px;border:0px;\" name=\"continue\" onclick=\"ok.performClick();\">Continue</button></body></html>";
[_tempWebView loadHTMLString:strUrl baseURL:nil];
```

I want to load this string to UIWebview and When I click on button , then I want to open my own viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do three things:

1. Override `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` delegate method of `UIWeBView`.
2. `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method returns a bool value so return false, then it will not load the link.
3. Inside this method write whatever functionality you want to perform.

Comment: This is source code

NSString *strUrl = @"<html><body><button type=\"button\" id=\"success_id\" style=\"width:200px;margin:0px auto;text-align:center; background:#1B2F77;color:#fff;padding:10px;font-size:10px;border:0px;\" name=\"continue\" onclick=\"ok.performClick();\">Continue</button></body></html>";
[_tempWebView loadHTMLString:strUrl baseURL:nil];
I want to load this string to UIWebview and When I click on button , then I want to open my own viewcontroller.

Comment: As per my understanding above code is not helpful. Please correct if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

If it is your page, communicate with app via JavaScript otherwise you can override shouldStartLoadWithRequest method and check if this specific request is called
some code:

```
- (BOOL)isItThatButtonEvent:(NSURLRequest *)req {
    if([req.URL.absoluteString isEqualString:@"that.specific.url.or.some.other.way.to.check.that"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

#pragma mark UIWebViewDelegate
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if([self isItThatButtonEvent:request]) {
        [self methodThatOpensYourViewController];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: When request will start loading, shouldStartLoadWithRequest method will call, then how can I call our own method on button click. Unable to understand , Please help.

Comment: if in request will be url from that specific link you can return false in this method and just before use whatever you want to use ie. open some other viewcontroller

Comment: Can you please share the source code for the same. I will highly obliged.